# Ember.js index of child components (for striping effect)

Tags: ember.js

I have two Ember js components: x-group and x-item. In my template they're arranged like this:

```
{{#x-group title='Park details'}}
  {{#x-item prop='poolSize'}}Pool Size{{/x-item}}
  {{#x-item prop='shelters'}}Shelters{{/x-item}}
  {{#x-item prop='benches'}}Benches{{/x-item}}
  {{#x-item prop='recRooms'}}Rec Center Rooms{{/x-item}}
  ...
{{/xgroup}}
```

The `{{x-item}}` template looks like:

```
{{#if prop}} <div>{{ yield }}: {{ prop }}</div>{{/if}}
```

I'm trying to stripe the **visible**, **odd** {{x-item}} elements.

Things I've tried:

- Finding an index for the child component--turned up a goose egg.
- Trying to create a css rule like `.group .item:nth-of-type(odd)` but the rule matches every `x-item`
- On `x-group` didInsertItem, using jQuery to find matching `item`s and setting my stripe color. This almost works except that if the `x-item` doesn't display the `x-group` still calculates it as though it were visible (even with a selector specifically meant to find only visible elements).

I'm open to any solution.

Comment: Definitely a useful question, any chance that you could post a fiddle or jsbin with an example of your code?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use nth-child(odd).  Try: .group .item:nth-child(odd)